# referencing a grouped date column using GETPIVOTDATA in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, pivot-table

I'm doing an analysis of sales data in Google Sheets and I'm building a dashboard with information about different sales reps. I'm trying to use the GETPIVOTDATA function to reference a year-quarter group in my pivot table, but I can't get the function to return the correct value.

In the pivot table, I have specific timestamps grouped by year-quarter and organised as columns. I have the individual sales reps and their teams organised as rows:
[Google Sheets pivot table][image: 1]. I want to use GETPIVOTDATA to get the number of SQLs for a specific sales rep in a specific quarter.

The function will only return the Grand Total for the sales rep (column F in the picture), or if the Grand Total is disabled in the pivot table, it returns a #REF! error.

I tried many iterations of the GETPIVOTDATA function. I also tried making a helper column in the original data that lists the specific year and quarter instead of the timestamp. Neither of these worked.

I realise that I can use an INDEX MATCH or VLOOKUP instead, but I want to be able to change the pivot table later without having to change the formula.

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong (or if what I'm trying to do is even possible with a GETPIVOTDATA function) I'd really appreciate advice! I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. Use [Markdown Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892)-all the data needed to answer your question must be in the question itself. [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.